Unable to change Kitty Icon
I'm trying to change the icon of kitty, yet rofi -show drun still shows the old one.
I tried copying the solution from here:
    { ... }:
    {
      nixpkgs.overlays = [
        (final: prev: {
          kitty = prev.kitty.overrideAttrs (o: {
            postInstall =
              (o.postInstall or "")
              + ''
                cp -f ${./kitty-dark.png} $out/share/icons/hicolor/256x256/apps/kitty.png
                rm -f $out/share/icons/hicolor/scalable/apps/kitty.svg
              '';
          });
        })
      ];
      programs.kitty = {
        enable = true;
        settings = {
          font_family = "JetBrainsMono Nerd Font Mono";
          bold_font = "JetBrainsMono Nerd Font Mono Extra Bold";
          bold_italic_font = "JetBrainsMono Nerd Font Mono Extra Bold Italic";
          enable_audio_bell = false;
        };
        keybindings = {
          "ctrl+shift+f" = "launch --type=overlay --stdin-source=@screen_scrollback fzf --no-sort --no-mouse --exact -i";
        };
        themeFile = "Catppuccin-Mocha";
      };
    }

I can successfully run home-manager switch, but the icon is not updated.
~/.config/home-manager/modules/kitty ls      
default.nix kitty-dark.png

I have tried rebooting (via $ reboot) and searching for solutions online. I don't understand why it is not working for me. I am using NixOS 25.05 on Hyprland.
